# como exportar imagenes de php a excel

Tags: php, excel, imagen

Hola tengo ya un archivo que me exporta una tabla a excel pero dicha tabla contiene imagenes las cuales no se exportan alguien me podria ayudar me urge un poco encontrar una solucion a este problema

Este es mi código para exportar pero no la imagen

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["exportar_datos"])) { 
$filename = "desarrollosnuevos.xls"; header("Content-Type: 
application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'"); 
$show_coloumn = false; 

if(!empty($arreglo)) { 
 foreach($arreglo as $record) { 
if(!$show_coloumn) {
echo implode("<br>", array_keys($record)) . "n"; 
$show_coloumn = true; 
} 
echo implode("<br>", array_values($record)) . "n";  
} 
} 
exit;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Para entender mejor la pregunta pon el código de donde exportas el excel

Comment: <?php

  if(isset($_POST["exportar_datos"])) {
$filename = "desarrollosnuevos.xls";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
$show_coloumn = false;
if(!empty($arreglo)) {
foreach($arreglo as $record) {
if(!$show_coloumn) {

echo implode("<br>", array_keys($record)) . "n";
$show_coloumn = true;
}
echo implode("<br>", array_values($record)) . "n";
}
}
exit;
}
?>

Comment: con esto yo ya puedo exportar mi tabla y los datos que contiene pero las imagenes no

Comment: Cuando se descarga y lo abre en excel en la parte donde se supone que tendrian que estar las imagenes me muestra este mensaje

Comment: No se puede mostrar la imagen vinculada. puede que se aya movido o cambiado de nombre o eliminado el archivo.

Comment: Le tienen que poner la ruta completa del servidor de donde lo esta tomando la imagen